# Design a Product entity with two user-dependent properties

Tags: database-design

I have a Product entity in my domain and two properties IsFavorite and IsHidden.

Each user can select some product to be favorited, hidden or no one of previous.

I have to give user a product list that contains NO "marked hidden" products and with a "star" near every favorite product.

In my mind come up a picture with two tables "Product" and "Product_User"

"Product_User" schema can be:
ProductId,
UserId,
IsFavorite,
IsHidden,

Is it correct?

During query time I have to query Product table excluding hidden products (so I have to query Product_User table before) and then mark each favorite product.

Comment: Yes.  The key point is to realise that `IsFavourite` and `IsHidden` aren't properties of Product - they are properties of the relationship between Product and User.  That's what Product_User represents.

Comment: I've retagged your question with the proper tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do DDD, there is no such things as schema or tables, because there is no database. There is only the domain model which models the problem for a specific bounded context.

I think  your question is clearly about the db schema, because at the domain level, you can have the ProductImpression(not quite the best name) property of a BoughtProduct object which is part of a BoughtProductsCollection object. Of course these are suggestions based on wild guesses as I don't know many details about the Domain.

As a schema I'd say something similar to waht you thought. A table containing the columns: Id, ProductId, UserId, ProductImpression .

This schema has the benefit that you can add more statuses in the future, without needing to change the schema.

Comment: ok, i have to start thinking different from what I have done 'till now with anemic domain